# How do I get myself to be attacked?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I’m a silver 3 player, and I’m going on to TH 7 (kinda trash too) I’m getting close to silver 2, but I’m afraid to do attacks, because I’m not that good at strategizing. I have pretty good defenses that haven't lost yet, so I just need to get attacked. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really anything you can do to get attacked more frequently other than removing the shield you get from being attacked and being offline as much as possible; being online means you can't be attacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can join a clan and send a challenge in the chat section and if people see it, they might attack you.

Answer (score -5):

Get the game on your second phone and then attack yourself

Comment: That would require him to get a second account up to Silver 3 and then go through the queue and try to find himself.